# How to store the string of the column in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I have attached a screenshot of my excel sheet. I want to store the length of every string in `SUPPLIER_id Length` column. But when I run my code, CSV columns are blanks.

And when I use this same code in different CSV, it works well.

I am using following code but not able to  print the data.

I have attached the snippet of csv. Can somebody tell me why is this happening:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/nba.csv')    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION'])    
data.dropna(inplace = True)    
data['SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(str)    
data['SUPPLIER_ID LENGTH']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].str.len()    
data['SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(float)    
data    
print(df)    
data.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/nba.csv")
```

Comment: Of course it would be empty because you are not doing anything with `df`.

Comment: (also please put code in codeblocks, [here's how to do it](https://puu.sh/DIn5c/ace9df7f2f.png), you can always check the little help button at the top right of your text box)

Comment: @amanb But he is saving the `data` variable and not the `df`. It should have worked. Don't you think the same?

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou, a few problems with the code: 1) `df` is unnecessary 2) Type casting 'SUPPLIER_ID' to `str` first and then again to `float` doesn't make sense. 3) Reading from and writing to the same csv 4) We cannot be sure if the csv will have any data in the end, without looking at the actual data.

Comment: i have attached the snippet of actual data.

Comment: SUPPLIER_ID contains integers in it. that's y I converted it in to string and then float. because I converted it for counting the length of integers.and also i want to write in the same csv file

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem in the past.

Instead of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION'])
```

Type this:

```
data.columns=['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION']
```

Also, I don't understand why did you create DataFrame df. It was unnecessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting a SettingWithCopyWarning from pandas? I would imagine (haven't ran this code) that these lines

```
data['SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(str)
data['SUPPLIER_ID LENGTH']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].str.len()    
data['SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(float)
```

would not do anything, and should be replaced with

```
data.loc[:, 'SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(str)  
data.loc[:, 'SUPPLIER_ID LENGTH']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].str.len()    
data.loc[:, 'SUPPLIER_ID']= data['SUPPLIER_ID'].astype(float)
```

Comment: I am not getting any error,just my csv goes blank when i run the code

Comment: I tried your code snippet as well but its not working for me. Y it is so, that the same code is working for other csv files but not for other.

Comment: Are you sure the original csv had data in it? you're reading and writing to the same file, if you've done any mistake the data might have been erased, if this code works for other csv files it should work on this one as well.

Comment: yes.when i am reading my csv(instead to giving  specific column name) as whole., few columns are gets erased.,i think that can be the issue.